# jQuery - Count up array

Tags: jquery, arrays, count

Just wondering how to I find out how many arrays are in a array and loop though them.
I want to create a back and next function which will allow a user to switch between 1,2,3,5,6

Comment: For someone who has posted 51 questions i'd expect a little more detail than this. Can you expand on what you mean by "Arrays in an Array" and "allow a user to switch between 1,2,3,5,6" also the big question: What have you already tried?

Comment: Is there a cryptic question badge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be reseaching the Javascript array object;

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

I think the property you are looking for is the `.length` property

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

Or are you talking about the number of elements selected in jquery using a selector?

In which case use the `.length` property again.

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: I am after the total array lenght so if there is 1,9,18 it should tell me there is 3 - 0,1,2